# Closing bracket ']' in LIKE wildcard

Tags: sql-server, query, sql-injection, like

I have a query that looks a bit like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Stuff WHERE name LIKE '[a\]]%'
```

My goal is to match all names starting with `a` or `]` (closed bracket). However, this seems to match everything starting with `a]` or `\\]`.

Is this possible without `OR`, a lot of auto-generated `LIKE`s?

Comment: Just want to understand is there any problem to use `LIKE` multiple  times i.e `name LIKE 'a%' or (name LIKE ']%')`

Comment: @ShekarKola My actual command has over 40 possible characters, so that would be a pretty long query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the ].
That means before any character you want to literally search for, example `%` or `_` or `]`, you have to add an `escape` character. For example `\%` to search for a literal `%`

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test( text varchar(50) )

INSERT INTO #test  VALUES (']'),('atest'),('zz')

SELECT * FROM #test  WHERE text LIKE '[a\]]%' {escape '\'}
```

To read more about escape chars in LIKE, you can check :

[LIKE Predicate Escape Character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/like-predicate-escape-character?view=sql-server-2017)

You can also test it using SQL fiddle:
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/aa3f09/1/0)

Comment: I escaped it in the query in my question. It doesn't work.

Comment: Check my example or the link, you have to add :  {escape '\'}

Comment: Hi @YannickLiekens, seems your example can only retrieves the rows that are starting with only `a]`. Cannot retrieves text starting with `a` which mentioned in OP

Comment: @ShekarKola Seems to be working fine? Added a SQL Fiddle link.

Comment: Hi @YannickLiekens, Fiddle got one "\" and your example got two "\\". Anyway, it works with **one** escape character

Comment: Ok, that's weird, I swear I tried that like ten times. Thanks!